# Angular2 using service to pass an object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a few components in my project that require previous steps to be completed before they can move on to the next step.

I have tried to create a function in my service, a file that they all share in common in order to facilitate the toggling of a status indicator.

**Service:**

```
// Loading indicator
private isLoading = {
    enabled: false,
    step: null
};

/**
 * Set the status for our loading indicator
 *
 * @param isLoading
 * @param step
 */
setLoader(isLoading, step) {
    this.isLoading = {
        enabled: isLoading,
        step: step
    };
    console.log(this.isLoading);
}
```

**A component:**

```
this._massEmpService.setLoader(true, 'step2');
```

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading?.enabled && isLoading?.step == 'step2'" class="loader" align="center">
  <img src="images/loading-bars.svg" alt="" />
</div>
```

When the button in my component is clicked, the function is called in the service and I see the object printed correctly. However, my HTML in another component is not showing based on this status change.

Can data not be passed through a service like this?

Comment: Have you considered using states to manage this flow?

Comment: @JakeHolzinger - It's so much the flow of things I am having trouble with. I just want to be able to toggle a loading indicator on components that are in the process of loading data that was triggered by another component to give some UI feedback. I assumed I could just set/unset this as needed to show the indicators when needed in the particular steps.

Comment: [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx) might be worth looking at.

Comment: Where do you declare provider for this service?

Comment: @AntonNikiforov In my app.module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is not updated because there were now `ApplicationRef.tick()` called.

You have two ways to improve that:

### 1. Return observable from your service

The implementation would be something like:

service.ts

```
import {Observable, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

export class Service {

    public isEnabled: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>();
    public step: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>();

    setLoader(isLoading, step) {
         this.isLoading = {
              enabled: isLoading,
              step: step
         };

         this.isEnabled.next(this.isLoading.enabled);
         this.step.next(this.isLoading.step);
         console.log(this.isLoading);
    }
}
```

component.ts:

```
@Component({})
export class Component {
     public isEnabled: Observable<boolean> = this.service.isEnabled;
     public step: Observable<number> = this.service.step;
}
```

component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="(isEnabled | async) && (step == 'step2' | async)" class="loader" align="center">
  <img src="images/loading-bars.svg" alt="" />
</div>
```

### 2. Implement "manually" informing view, that it should be updated.

It would be:

```
import {ApplicationRef} from '@angular/core';

export class Service {
     constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef) {}
     setLoader(isLoading, step) {
          this.isLoading = {
               enabled: isLoading,
               step: step
          };
          console.log(this.isLoading);
          this.appRef.tick();
     }
}
```

More about ApplicationRef: https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef

The choice depends on you. It depends on what more fits your needs.

Comment: Is what I am doing a hackey approach to my issue or is it okay to use the service in this manner?

Comment: ApplicationRef is a little bit hacky. Give me a sec, I will update answer with observable :)

Comment: Ok. Updated. :)

Comment: I am getting this type script error : `[ts] Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<boolean>'.`

Comment: Ahh sorry :) Change the declaration type to BehaviorSubject. I will update my answer again :)

Comment: Now it is better?

Comment: Last question, how would I set this within my component? I added the lines to it that you have provided but then in my button function, I tried to do `this.isEnabled = true; this.step = 'step2';` and I get the error of `[ts] Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149759/discussion-between-maciej-treder-and-sbb).

Comment: You should go through the service method. `setLoader(true, 'step2')`